# Error 43 using openlayers, Geoserver, and WMTS

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wmts

When attempting to use the WMTS tile service with Geoserver and openlayers I keep getting error 43 (Expected layers to be an array or an ol.Collection.). I am new to openlayers so the issue is likely trivial but I can't figure it out.

```
 var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326');
 var projectionExtent = projection.getExtent();
 var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
 var mapExtent =  [-13884991, 2870341, -7455066, 6338219];
 var resolutions = new Array(22);
 var matrixIds = new Array(22);

 for (var z = 0; z < 22; ++z) {
   // generate resolutions and matrixIds arrays for this WMTS
   resolutions[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
   matrixIds[z] = z;
 }

 layers = new ol.layer.Tile({
       source: new ol.source.WMTS({
       url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts',
        layer: 'Aberdeen:TAC_ALL',
       matrixSet: 'EPSG:4326',
       format: 'image/png',
       projection: projection,
       tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
           origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
           resolutions: resolutions,
           matrixIds: matrixIds
         })
   })
});

 var map = new ol.Map({
   layers: layers,
   target: 'map',
   view: new ol.View({
     center: [-10997148, 4569099],
     zoom: 4
   })
 });
```

Comment: your map is in 3857 not 4326 so you either need to change it or the gridset you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
layers = new ol.layer.Tile({ ...
});
```

is only one layer
so you need to specify

```
layers: [layers],
```

to make it an array

Comment: That is incredibly annoying how easy of a fix that was. Thanks